# How to infer correct element type for empty invariant collection (e.g. Set)

Tags: scala

In a case class I had to change one argument the constructor from `String` to `Set[String]`.
For backwards compatibility I have now added a companion object with an overloaded apply function.

```
case class OldClass (x: String, y: Set[String] = Set()) {}

case class NewClass(x: Set[String], y: Set[String] = Set()) {}

object NewClass {
    def apply(x: String): NewClass = NewClass(Set(x), Set[String]())
    def apply(x: String, y: Set[String]): NewClass = NewClass(Set(x), y)
}
```

Now this works:

```
val c = NewClass("xxx", Set[String]())
```

But how can I make this work:

```
val c = NewClass("xxx", Set())
```

I need this, because I have some code that relies on being able to create a `NewClass` like this

Im getting the Error:

```
overloaded method value apply with alternatives (x:String) <and> (x: String,y: Set[String]) cannot be applied to (String, scala.collection.immutable.Set[Nothing])
```

Comment: I just tried to reproduce the error and wasn't able to. `NewClass("xxx", Set())` works fine for me. Mb you typed `NewClass(Set("xxx", Set()))` ?

Comment: I also do not get an error in IntelliJ. But when i compile it using maven I get the error

Comment: I've checked in scala repl. Are you able to reproduce error there? If "no", mb cleaning project would help.

Comment: BTW, it would be better to call `Set.empty` instead.

Comment: I also cannot reproduce it in repl. I tried using the latest version of maven-scala plugin and it also did not help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that constructor `Set()` yields a value of type `Set[Nothing]` which is not `Set[String]`. To make this work precisely as you want, you can use not very reliable but working approach by adding another constructor that actually allows Set[Nothing]:

```
  case class NewClass(x: Set[String], y: Set[String]) {}

  object NewClass {
    def apply(x: Set[String]): NewClass = NewClass(x, Set.empty[String])
    def apply(x: String): NewClass = NewClass(Set(x), Set[String]())
    def apply(x: String, y: Set[String]): NewClass = NewClass(Set(x), y)
    def apply(x: String, y: Set[Nothing], z: Unit = ()): NewClass = NewClass(Set(x), Set.empty[String])
  }

  val c = NewClass("xxx", Set())
```

Note that `z: Unit = ()` default parameter added only and only to distinguish these two constructors after generics type erasure, and default parameter `y = Set.empty[String]` was deleted because first constructor actually restores such syntax. I don't recommend using this approach in real code, because, well that's,  a pretty counter-intuitive hack.

Comment: I know its kind of a hack, but thats what I was looking for. I've come to the point where i added Set[Nothing], but then in conflicted with the other apply function. With the z its not nice, but it should do the job. Thank you